# ListView get_context_data

Tags: django, django-views

question about Django.
Would like to ask you guys if it's possible to use get_context_data in ListView?

I am interested in using the following template tags in my ListView:

```
{% if liked %}
<i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
{% else %}
<i class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up"></i> 
{% endif %}
```

This works in my DetailView but I can't figure out how to implement it in ListView maybe you guys can help me?

This is my views.py

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):

    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.object.comments.order_by('-created_on')
        context['liked'] = self.object.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists()
        return context
```

I'm testing get_context_data i ListView but can't get it to work.
I get the following message: This is the response error : AttributeError at /blog/ 'PostList' object has no attribute 'object'
Please need help :)

Comment: Yes it's possible. You use it the same way as with `DetailView`. The only issue is that while DetailView is expecting a single item, ListView is expecting a list of items. so `liked` would not necessarily work unless you get the likes for all result or likes for a single item

Comment: Yup I'm trying to get for a single item but it doesn't work, so help is needed that's why I post on this forum :S

Comment: use `.annotate` but with filter. Check [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) on django docs